# How access ActionBar from fragment on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

On my application I have only one activity (that extends ActionBarActivity ) and various Fragments (that extends Fragment).
When the user click on a menu option, the application change the Fragment.
At this moment I want to change de title and the background color of the ActionBar.
When I try `ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();` I got a null exception.

I'm using support library, and on the Activity I'm using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` successfully.

On the Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.material_cadastro, container, false);

    viewHolder = new MaterialViewHolder(view);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.inserir_material);

    return view;
}
```

Debuging I got that the Activity is returning OK, but the ActionBar is null:

```
getActivity() = {br.com.americocarelli.vendasfacil.ui.MenuPrincipal@3b56766f}
getActivity().getActionBar() = null
```

Comment: Are you using support library?

Comment: Do your fragments have proper ID's or tags set? I believe you need to set either the tag or the ID of each fragment in order for getActivity() to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override your `onAttach(Activity)`, then cast your `Activity` to `ActionBarActivity`, the you can get an `ActionBar`.
Like:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ActionBar actionBar=((ActionBarActivity)activity).getSupportActionBar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to override as you mention! My code was on `onCreateView`, and worked too!

Comment: overriding `onAttach` is recommended, because `onAttach` is called before `onCreateView`

Comment: `onCreateView` is mainly used for creating views.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the support library (ActionBarActivity), then use `((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();` to get access to the support action bar.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked like a charm! `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();`

Comment: *cast-to* class is deprecated .  Now it is; `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably building it with build tools >=21, that versions causes activity.getActionBar() returns null, you should use getSupportActionBar() instead. 
EDIT: if you get NPE at exactly this line: getActivity(). ... then you are probably referencing it before or after fragment is attached to activity. Could you please paste the context (place, in what function) you are using it?